# Position of GUI.Label in Unity3D

Tags: user-interface, text, unity-game-engine, position, label

I have a huge (but probably simple) problem. I want to display score. I'm using GUI.Label. When I scale GUI.Label. I want to set position of text. I work on Android, so there are many resolutions and aspect ratios, and I have problem with giving it a precise position.

The "GAME OVER" text is sprite. I tried to set position as half of screen height. It works on some devices, but it doesn't work on devices with highest resolution (1280x720). When I set 400px from top it works, but it doesn't make any sense. Is there any tip for this? I want to display score like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Jylpjmj7sw).

My code:

```
private string labelText;
public Font fontxd;

public Vector2 sizexde;
/*[HideInInspector]*/public GUIStyle styl;

public int p,hp;

static GameObject g1;
static punkt playerScript;

static float virtualWidth  = 640.0f;
static float virtualHeight = 400.0f;
static Rect rece;
static Vector3 v3;
public Matrix4x4 matrixs;
static float guiRatio=Screen.width/640;
static float XD=0;

void Start() //1280x720
{
    if (Screen.width > Screen.height) {
        XD=Screen.width/2;
    } 

    else{//if( Screen.height>Screen.width ){
        XD=Screen.height/2;
    }

    rece=new Rect(10,XD, Screen.width,1);

    v3 = new Vector3 (Screen.width / virtualWidth, Screen.width / virtualWidth , 1.0f);
    matrixs = Matrix4x4.TRS (Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, v3);
    g1 = GameObject.Find("XDXDX2");
    playerScript = g1.GetComponent<punkt>();    
}

void OnGUI() 
{
    p = playerScript.punkty;
    hp = playerScript.hpunkty;
    labelText = "Height: " + Screen.height+"-"+Screen.height/2 + "\nWidth: " + Screen.width + "-"+Screen.width/2 ;

    GUI.matrix = matrixs;
    styl.normal.textColor = Color.black;
    styl.font = fontxd;
    styl.fontSize = 70;

    GUI.Label (rece, labelText, styl);
}
```

Comment: snapshot needed, do not link to youtube, there are so many frames, and which score display do you want?

Answer (score 0):

- GameObject > CreateOther > GUIText
- Edit settings in inspect as shown below:

[image]

Now your label's position should be resolution independent.

[image][image]